# Count unread messages in chats after last read message id in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, chat

I have a chat in an app and need to select unread messages for given chats.

Each chat can have multiple users and for each user I store last read message id per chat.
[image]

Here is select for user chats with all messages count:

```sql
select c.id, count(cm.id)
from chats_users cu
inner join chats c
on c.id = cu.chat_id
left join chat_messages cm
on cm.chat_id = c.id
where cu.user_id = 1
group by c.id
```

How to modify this query so it counts only messages after `chats_users.last_read_message_id` per chat?

*Solution query from comments*

```sql
select c.id, count(cm.id)
from chats_users cu
inner join chats c
on c.id = cu.chat_id
left join chat_messages cm
on cm.chat_id = c.id
and cm.id > cu.last_read_message_id
where cu.user_id = 1
group by c.id
```

It almost works, but shows incorrectly 0 when `cu.last_read_message_id` is `null`.

Comment: `on cm.chat_id = c.id and cm.id > cu.last_read_message_id` ?

Comment: @Serg I've tried it and it works, but when `cu.last_read_message_id` is `null` it shows incorrectly 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you don't need the join to `chats`:

```
select cu.chat_id, count(cm.id)
from chats_users cu left join
     chat_messages cm
     on cm.chat_id = cu.chat_id and
        (cm.id > cu.last_read_message_id or
         cu.last_read_message_id is null
        )
where cu.user_id = 1
group by cu.chat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a null condition, seems to be working:

```sql
select c.id, count(cm.id)
from chats_users cu
inner join chats c
on c.id = cu.chat_id
left join chat_messages cm
on cm.chat_id = c.id
and (cm.id > cu.last_read_message_id or cu.last_read_message_id is null)
where cu.user_id = 1
group by c.id
```

If there is a better solution, please post as an answer.